# how long to wait before select an answer

Tags: support, accepted-answer

hello,
I made a question some days ago. I have only received one answer but it  seems like personal research, no references are given but it seems at least credible.

I think I wont get a better answer. Should I mark the question as accepted anyway? Is there any policy of how to handle this?

My question is this:
[Does the Tyrolean crossing (zip line) from Tyrol?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3798/tyrolean-crossing-zip-line-really-from-tyrol/4132#4132)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only accept an answer that you feel answers your question successfully. If you feel the only answer you've got isn't good enough, don't accept it and leave a comment explaining why. With a little bit of luck, the user, or another user, will use that information to write a better answer.

As for how long? I always give it 24-48 hours. Just to give everyone a chance.

Comment: @santiagozky If you have an answer, and still don't like it, try offering a bounty too (once you establish enough reputation to do so).